# How to make a div draggable on another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to make a div dragable over the another div . How to do this ?

This is my html and i made this responsive using media query

```
<style>
    .text-canvas{
        z-index:1;
        position:absolute;
    }
    .imageupload{
        z-index:-1;
    }
</style>

<script>
    function submit_button(){
    alert('hiii');
   }

</script>
<div class="parent-canvas">
      <div class="text-canvas" contenteditable="true">
        my text
     </div>
     <div class="image-canvas">
         <div class="imageupload" onclick="submit_button()">
            <img src="img.png">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here i need to make this text-canvas div dragabble, so that user can drag that my text and he can place it on any where in the image (only inside image-canvas div   ).
I see the html drag and drop , but i didn't understand how to apply this .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your html :  Add this script

```
$( ".text-canvas"").draggable({
    containment: ".imageupload"
});
```

For any doubts in syntax or working check these documents

(1) http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

(2) https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Make sure you already included jquery-ui.js . First you need to call jquery.js or jquery.min.js then only call jquery-ui.js , the order is important. 
eg:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check Out HTML5 Drag And Drop

[HTML5 Drag & Drop](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop)

Answer (score 0):

Create targets for draggable elements.Enable any DOM element to be droppable, a target for draggable elements.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
  #droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The jQuery UI Droppable plugin makes selected elements droppable (meaning they accept being dropped on by draggables). You can specify which draggables each will accept.

Theming

The droppable widget uses the jQuery UI CSS framework to style its look and feel. If droppable specific styling is needed, the following CSS class names can be used for overrides or as keys for the classes option:

ui-droppable: The droppable element. When a draggable that can be dropped on this dropppable is activated, the ui-droppable-active class is added. When dragging a draggable over this droppable, the ui-droppable-hover class is added.

link https://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Answer (score 0):

See the Draggable example from jQuery UI [here](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)